# Mschart polar - dont draw lines to the edge

Tags: c#, mschart

When i use polar charts in mschart and some of the datapoints is outside the Y-scale (the visible area), the lines that should be connected to the datapoints outside are not drawn. This occurs both when the Y-value is bigger that the AxisY.Maximum and when the chart is zoomed. Is it possible to get mschart to draw the missing lines to the edge of the chart instead?

I have a formula to calculate the points at the edge that i can use to replace the outside points with, but i Think it only will solve the problem when the chart is not zoomed.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this. However I think adding the points on the border should help. Can you try and post the code?